# Java comparison of two String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a Question about comparing two String Arrays in an efficient way. I want to know which String of stArr1 contains any String of stArr2.
If yes I want to print the String in which I found it and the index of the String in the stArr1.

What I got so far is an easy way of comparing two strings:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] stArr1 = {"I am testing", "hi", "bye bye"};
        String[] stArr2 = {"hello", "bye", "test"};

        int matches = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < stArr1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < stArr2.length; j++) {
                if (stArr1[i].contains(stArr2[j])) {
                    System.out.println(stArr1[i] + "found at index " i);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the output should be: I am testing found at index 0, bye bye found at index 2.

Does anybody know a more efficient way? I tried a little bit with streams and am pretty sure there is a better solution than that.

Comment: I am sorry, I was in a rush and I didn't take my time to truly review this question, forget about what I have said, you code is right and efficient, whilst being easy to read and understand.

Comment: does "_an efficient way_" mean fastest execution time? least use of memory? fewest lines of code?

Comment: @user85421  The OP implied by example that they wanted to find multiple matches so all strings should be checked.

Comment: There is a solution that would be potentially more efficient, but it has nothing to do with the Stream API. You have to decide what your question is about, a Stream API solution or a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `IntStream` combined with the `anyMatch` operator to get this thing done. Streams API is versatile such that any practical computation can be performed using streams. But, just because you can, doesn't mean you should. I still prefer the iterative approach and it is much more readable than the streams solution at least to me. So, my recommendation to you is to keep the iterative solution.

```
IntStream.range(0, stArr1.length)
    .filter(i -> Arrays.stream(stArr2).anyMatch(s -> stArr1[i].contains(s)))
    .forEach(i -> System.out.println(stArr1[i] + " found at index " + i));
```